# jQuery Help In Dreamweaver

Tags: jquery, dreamweaver

I'm new to HTML/jQuery and I am struggling to solve a problem. My goal is to make it so when you click a box (#boxone), an image appears in a different box (#boximage).

I'm not sure if there is an error in my code or a problem with dream weaver loading it. Any help it greatly appreciated!

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#boxone').click(function(){
        $("#boximage").attr('src',"http://i.minus.com/iPbqANEnXrXtb.png");
    return false;
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap jQuery code inside their own `<script>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#boxone').click(function(){
            $("#boximage").attr('src',"http://i.minus.com/iPbqANEnXrXtb.png");
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, seems so simple but I couldn't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

the code there is for swapping the url of an existing image, if you want to change an image inside a div you would either need to change the background image, or append an image to the div

```
$('#boximage').css("background-image", "url(http://i.minus.com/iPbqANEnXrXtb.png)");

$('#boximage').prepend('<img src="http://i.minus.com/iPbqANEnXrXtb.png" />')
```

Answer (score 0):

you missed the end script tag in your first line...and add starting script tag in second..

it should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#boxone').click(function(){
    $("#boximage").attr('src',"http://i.minus.com/iPbqANEnXrXtb.png");
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```